# How to 'reverse sum' in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, math

I have no clue how to call this in correct math-terms. Consider a method which takes two digits:

```
 def num_of_sum(total, group_count)

 end
```

where `total` is an integer and `group_count` is an integer.

How would I get a 'nicely' grouped Array of integers of `group_count`-length which sum up till `total`.

My spec would look like:

```
describe "number to sum of" do
  it "grabs all numbers" do
    expect(num_of_sum(10, 2)).to eq([5,5])
    expect(num_of_sum(10, 3)).to eq([3,3,4])
    expect(num_of_sum(20, 3)).to eq([6,7,7])
    expect(num_of_sum(100, 3)).to eq([33,33,34])
    expect(num_of_sum(100, 2)).to eq([50,50])
  end
end
```

I tried this, which works:

```
def num_of_sum(total, in_groups_of)
  result = []
  section_count ||= (total.to_f / in_groups_of.to_f).round

  while(total > 0)
    total -= section_count

    if (total - section_count) < 0 && (total + section_count).even?
      section_count += total
      total -= total
    end

    result << section_count
  end

  result
end
```

But, for instance, this spec doesn't work:

```
 expect(num_of_sum(67,5)).to eq([13,13,13,14,14])
```

I need the array to contain numbers that are as close to each other as possible. But the array is limited to the length of the `group_count`.

---

Does someone know what the mathemetical name for this is, so I can search a bit more accurately?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def n_parts(num, groupcount)
  div, mod = num.divmod(groupcount)
  Array.new(groupcount-mod, div) + Array.new(mod, div+1)
end

n_parts(100,3) => [33, 33, 34]
```

Docs to [Array.new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-c-new) and [Fixnum.divmod](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Fixnum.html#method-i-divmod)

Comment: `[div] * (groupcount-mod) + [div+1] * mod` for the Array-addition line would save 15 bytes.

Comment: `[d]*(g-m)+[d+1]*m` saves even more. :-)

Comment: That would be the first @Fietsband liking steenslag.

Answer (score 6):

The mathematical term for this is an integer [partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory))

A more direct approach to this is to observe that if you do integer division (round down) of the total by the number of groups, then your sum would be short by total mod number_of_groups, so you just need to distribute that amount across the array:

```
def even_partition(total, number_of_groups)
  quotient, remainder = total.divmod(number_of_groups)
  (number_of_groups-remainder).times.collect {quotient} +
  remainder.times.collect { quotient + 1}    
end
```

Answer (score 5):

A naive implementation is like this:

Let's take example of `(20, 3)`. You want three numbers as a result.

```
20 / 3 # => 6
```

This is your "base" value. Create an array of three sixes, `[6, 6, 6]`. That'll get you 18. Now you have to distribute remaining 2 as equally as possible. For example, enumerate array elements and increment each one by 1, until you have no value to distribute. Result is `[7, 7, 6]`. Good enough, I think.

Possible (working) implementation:

```
def breakdown(total, group_count)
  avg_value, extra = total.divmod(group_count)

  result = Array.new(group_count, avg_value)
  extra.times do |i|
    result[i] += 1
  end

  result
end

breakdown(10, 2) == [5, 5] # => true
breakdown(10, 3) == [4, 3, 3] # => true
breakdown(20, 3) # => [7, 7, 6]
```

Comment: Came up with this answer after some puzzling! :) Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue how it’s called, but here is a solution:

```
def num_of_sum sum, count
  result = [i = sum / count] * count # prepare an array e.g. [3,3,3] for 10,3
  result[sum - i * count..-1] + # these should be left intact
    result[0...sum - i * count].map { |i| i + 1 } # these are ++’ed
end
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
def floors_then_ceils(n, groups)
  floor, ceils = n.divmod(groups)
  groups.times.map { |i| (i < groups-ceils) ? floor : floor + 1 }
end

floors_then_ceils(10, 3)
  #=> [3, 3, 4] 
floors_then_ceils(9, 3)
  #=> [3, 3, 3]
```

Alternatively, `groups.times.map...` could be replaced with:

```
Array.new(groups-ceils, floor).concat(Array.new(ceils, floor+1))
```